# How to refactor to reduce if statements?

Tags: java, refactoring

Given this config class the code smell is there, that there are to much if statements. Also there will be a lot more class variables which will be added. Actually I am creating this MailConfig Object with a static factory method fromAttributes which will take a list of attributes. Now as you can see in the mapToConfig it is the same way so set the values of the MailConfig. But there will be also special attributes which need a more complex handling. How can I refactor this, to reduce the amount of ifs? For example as next there will be a new

```
private final String mailServer
```

this would required to add a new if in the mapToConfig method as well ...

```
    import lombok.Builder;
    import lombok.Data;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;

    @Data
    @Builder
    public class MailConfig {

        private final String subject;
        private final String mailserver;
        private final String message;


        public static MailConfig fromAttributes(List<Attribute> listofAttributes) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(listofAttributes, "list of attributes must not be null");
            MailConfigBuilder config = MailConfig.builder();
            listofAttributes.stream()
                    .forEach(att -> mapToConfig(config, att));
            return config.build();
        }

        private static void mapToConfig(MailConfigBuilder config, Attribute att) {
            if (att.getAttribName().equalsIgnoreCase("subject")){
                config.subject(att.getAttribValue());
            }
            if (att.getAttribName().equalsIgnoreCase("mailserver")){
                config.mailserver(att.getAttribValue());
            }
            if (att.getAttribName().equalsIgnoreCase("message")){
                config.message(att.getAttribValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Java 8+? If yes, you could use a map

```
class MapExample {

    public static void mapper(Object o) throws Exception {
        //initializing here, really should do this outside the function of course
        Map<String, Runnable> routes = new HashMap<>();

        //populate map
        routes.put('subject', () -> config.subject(o.getAttribValue));
        //and so on, for all cases

        //use like this
        String example = att.getAttribName();
        routes.get(example).run();   // runs the method mapped to "subject" above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use if/else, to leave when one of the conditions is true, or use a switch case to do the same.

You have to verify that attNameis not null, and attribValueis not null either.

```
private static void mapToConfig(MailConfigBuilder config, String attName, String attribValue) {

    switch (attName.toLowerCase()) {
        case "subject":
            config.subject(attribValue);
            break;
        case "mailserver":
            config.mailserver(attribValue);
            break;              
        case "message":
            config.message(attribValue);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Pass only the attributes needed, not the whole Attribute object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static map of type `Map<String, BiConsumer<MailConfigBuilder, Attribute>>` to get rid of the if else block

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

@Data
@Builder
public class MailConfig {

    private final String subject;
    private final String mailserver;
    private final String message;

    private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<MailConfigBuilder, Attribute>> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put("subject",    (mailConfBuil, atr) -> {mailConfBuil.subject(atr.getAttribValue());});
        map.put("mailserver", (mailConfBuil, atr) -> {mailConfBuil.mailserver(atr.getAttribValue());});
        map.put("message",    (mailConfBuil, atr) -> {mailConfBuil.message(atr.getAttribValue());});
    }

    public static  MailConfig fromAttributes(List<Attribute> listofAttributes) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(listofAttributes, "list of attributes must not be null");
        MailConfigBuilder config = MailConfig.builder();
        listofAttributes.stream()
                .forEach(att -> mapToConfig(config, att));
        return config.build();
    }

    private static void mapToConfig(MailConfigBuilder config, Attribute att) {
        map.get(att.getAttribName()).accept(config, att);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks interesting, did not use BiConsumer before, will take a look into.